# Does unsigned in C do any internal job?

Tags: c, unsigned

It's been a while since I start programming in C, however, I still feel confused about `unsigned`. If we compiled this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned int x = -1;

    return 0;
}
```

both gcc and VC++ don't raise any error or even a warning regarding using negative number with `unsigned`.

My question is that does `unsigned` do any internal job or it just a ***hint*** to the programer that this value shouldn't be negative?

Comment: Obviously you are compiling without any optimization enabled..

Comment: Raise your warning level higher. MSVC does have a warning for this, but it requires `/W4`, I'm sure GCC does too.

Comment: -Wall -pedantic did not show any warning about a signed int being assigned to a unsigned int.

Comment: since this is well defined behaviour and gives you the highest possible unsigned int, why do you expect a warning at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is NOT just a hint.  The following two snippets should behave differently:

Signed int:

```
int x = -1;
printf("%d\n", x > 0);  // prints 0
```

Unsigned int:

```
unsigned int x = -1;
printf("%d\n", x > 0);  // prints 1
```

And you could probably come up with 5 more examples where the signedness matters.  For example, shifting right with the `>>` operator.

Comment: Not to mention that you can safely overflow an unsigned number but not a signed one :)

Comment: @Joey There obviously are at least 10 programmers who don't bother, but technically it's not even an overflow, but just modulo arithmetics

Answer (score 2):

Use `-Wsign-conversion` to get a warning with `gcc`.

With `gcc` 4.7.1, `-Wsign-conversion` is neither a part of `-Wall` nor  `-Wextra`.

Also note that the C Standard does NOT require a warning for this initialization.

Answer (score 2):

`unsigned` is not a qualifier like `static`, `extern`, `const` or `inline`. It is part of the type.

`int` and `unsigned int` are two completely different types. You will never find an `unsigned int` that can hold a negative number. Note also that `int` and `signed int` are exactly the same type. It's a slightly different story for `char`, but I'll leave that for another time.

Assigning `-1` to an unsigned integer is a common trick to set it to the largest value it can hold.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable warnings in gcc by: `gcc -Wall -o out input.c`

Another difference between `unsigned int` and normal `int`: `int` range using 4-bytes: –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, `unsigned` range using 4-bytes: 0 to 4,294,967,295 . You don't have to store information about the sign (the highest bit) so you can assign larger values and the application will work properly.

Comment: `-Wall` does not print the warning on my `gcc` version.

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned` can affect integer overflow, comparison, and bitwise-shift behavior. It is not just a "hint" that it should not be negative.

Answer (score 0):

`((unsigned int) -1)` is equivalent to `(UINT_MAX)` (`<limits.h>`), because a conversion from a negative value to an unsigned value is guaranteed to be done by a modulo operation.

> **C11 § 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is `unsigned`, the value is converted by
> repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
> can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
> the new type.

Answer (score -1):

There are both signed and unsigned versions of the internal(machine-level) instructions for calculations such as multiplication `mul`(for unsigned) and `imul`(signed). Compiler chooses them as you declare variables as unsigned or signed.

Comment: What the compiler does is rarely relevant. Signed and unsigned integers are defined by certain *semantics*; how they are implemented is merely a consequence of that.